# export files through a loop each in a new folder?

Tags: python, loops

To make you understand. I have this loop:

```
for i,v in zip(ps,db):
    print(i,v)

C:\Users\user\Desktop\sa\43001\PST\PST.shp C:\Users\user\Desktop\sa\43001\DBOUND\DBOUND.shp
C:\Users\user\Desktop\sa\43003\PST\PST.shp C:\Users\user\Desktop\sa\43003\DBOUND\DBOUND.shp
```

For each export in each iteration I want the exported file to be put in a new folder according to the number in the directory of the files used.
Example: Create folder named `43001` that has the `PST.shp` created of the files from the 43001 directory. Then a folder named `43003` that has the corresponding `PST.shp`.

This code is close to the wanted but needs a fix to create those folders.

```
for i, v in zip(ps,db):
    db1 = gpd.read_file(v)
    pst1 = gpd.read_file(i)
    wdp = gpd.sjoin(pst1, db1, how="left", op='within')
    o = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\resultss'
    out = o +'\\'+i.split("\\")[-3] +'PST.shp'
    wdp.to_file(out)
```

**The problem with this:**

This code creates the files as `43001PST.shp` and `43002PST.shp` in the `resultss` folder instead of creating the folders with the numbers as names with `PST.shp` in them as it should. What should be changed?

The wanted is:

```
resultss>>43001>>PST.shp
resultss>>43003>>PST.shp
```

Comment: You want to know how to create a directory?

Comment: `os.mkdir(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\resultss\' + i.split("\\")[-3])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `.to_file()` method handles creating the directories, try this:

```
out = o + '\\' + i.split("\\")[-3] + '\\PST.shp'
```

If it doesn't, create the directory first by calling `os.mkdir()` before `.to_file()`:

```
import os
os.mkdir(o + '\\' + i.split("\\")[-3])
```

Comment: I have tried this but doesn't work gives CPLE_AppDefinedError

Comment: Does the folder exist? If not, can you try creating it? Either manually, or by adding `os.mkdir(o + '\\' + i.split("\\")[-3])` before calling `.to_file()`.

Comment: The comment you made solved the problem. If you want update your answer.